# Support of a locally integrable distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

The support of a distribution $T$ defined on an open set $\Omega$ is defined as follows :
Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the set of **open** subsets $V \subset \Omega$ that satisfy : $\text{supp}\varphi \subset V \implies T(\varphi)=0$

Then the support of $T$ is the **complement** of $\displaystyle{ \cup_{V \in \mathscr{A}}} V$.
Equivalently, for $x \in \Omega$, $x$ is in the support of $T$ iff for any neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ there exists $\varphi$ with support in $N$ such that $T(\varphi) \neq 0$.

What I mean by locally integrable distribution is a distribution $\varphi \mapsto \int \varphi f$ where $f$ is locally integrable. I would like an example proving that the support of $f$ can differ from that of its corresponding distribution.

An interesting comment by TZakrevskiy pointed out to me that the support of a locally integrable function may be a dodgy topic as it is only defined almost everywhere. However in my lecture notes it does precisely say that the support of $f$ may differ from thay of its distribution $T_f$.

Comment: What do you understand under the support of $f$ here? Integrable functions are defined up to a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: True... let me define that in my post.

Comment: I think the best course of action is to ask the professor what he had in mind what he told that.

Otherwise, the naïve approach would be to take $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1,&x\in\Bbb Q,\\0,&x\notin\Bbb Q.\end{cases}$$ The support of this object as a function is $\Bbb R$, yet its support in distributional sense is $\emptyset$.

Comment: This example is perfect.